# MessageBodyReader error when deploying to AnyPoint Runtime Fabric from GitHub using Azure Pipieline

Tags: anypoint-platform, anypoint-rtf, mule-maven-plugin

Last week  I could deploy my project without error and now I am getting this when I try to deploy the same code set from GitHub to AnyPoint Runtime Fabric (RTF) via an Azure Pipeline.
what would cause the change?

```
Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.7.1:deploy (default-deploy) on project int-corerms-helms: 
Execution default-deploy of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.7.1:deploy failed: 
MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class org.mule.tools.client.arm.model.Environments, genericType=class org.mule.tools.client.arm.model.Environments.
```

Answer (score 0):

That error could happen if you are trying to deploy to Anypoint Runtime Fabric using a Connected App credentials for authentication in Mule Maven Plugin and the Connected App doesn't has the right [scope added](https://docs.mulesoft.com/access-management/connected-apps-developers#endpoint-scopes).

All the following scopes need to be added:

- Create Applications
- Manage Runtime Fabrics
- Manage Settings
- Read Applications
- Exchange Contributors
- Design Center Developer

See more details on this KB article: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/RTF-Deployment-With-Connected-App-Is-Failing